# MS Access Form Not Filtering On Load

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that lists several requests. When someone clicks on the request ID it opens a review form, closing the list form. An individual fills out the review form and changes the status, then clicks a button to close the current form and opens the list form again.

When the list form opens again, I'd like it to filter only those requests that are Submitted or Re-Submitted when it loads. When a review happens in the review form, the status changes to Pending. The form closes and opens the list form which shows the status as Pending. I don't want this, I don't want any Pending to show, only Submitted or Re-Submitted.

This is the VBA code I'm using, but its not working when the form loads.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "RequestID ASC"
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "[RequestStatus] IN ('Submitted', 'Re-Submitted')"
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You're probably off best adjusting the VBA that opens the form, not this `Form_Load` piece. Can you share it?

Comment: Actually it's a basic macro that opens the form (OpenForm: frmAdminListToDo, View: Form, Window Mode: Normal. Then a CloseWindow Macro (Object Type: Form, Object Name: frmReviews, Save: Yes.

Comment: Well, my point stands, the `OpenForm` macro action has a `Where condition` section

Comment: So add the filter in the Where Condition?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do a Me.Requery -- I am wondering if your source recordset in the receiving form is stale.

Comment: Me.Requery did not work on form load. How do I check if the source recordset in the receiving form is stale?

Comment: Oh, good point - this is a loading form. A long shot, but sometimes MS Access reacts slowly to data changes. I've seen it happen. Not saying that's the case here, though. In the off chance that's the issue, test this -- add a button to the form, and on the click event do the Me.Requery. If the data shows up then, but not on the Load event, that's the cause. If it doesn't show up even on the button click, then pause code during the button click and review the SQL behind the recordsource, the filter property, and the FilterOn property. You should find your smoking gun at that point.